# Pull a helm chart locally in a lambda to run some validations

Tags: java, lambda, containers, kubernetes-helm, amazon-ecr

I’m trying to figure out how we can download/pull a helm chart from the Java code ( Lambda) to perform some validations on the helm chart. How we normally pull helm chart → We have helm CLI installed on our dev box and that helm CLI interface will go to the ECR repository and pull the helm chart for us locally like HELM PULL CHART …. We need to have some sort of helm client which pulls it for us in lambda code package and then we should be able to read the helm chart and perform certain validations in the code itself and provide output.
Biggest problem : we don’t have a helm Java client through which we can make calls to ECR repository to pull the helm chart from the java code we have. Any idea how this can be done ? Thanks

Looked into lamdbda layers, but nothing fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

you may wanna have a look at https://github.com/helm-unittest/helm-unittest

even if you manage to pull the helm chart, you will not exactly be able to parse it (unless you run *helm template* first) since it is not spec compliant yaml with the helm template expressions in there.